# EJS in Express.js - Express Helpers not working - (app) in require

Tags: node.js, express, view-helpers, ejs

I'm using the EJS template engine with express.js and I want to use the view helpers. I found this on github: https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers, but when I try to use it I get this error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION (native)
at Object. (/home/node/app/app.js:12:40)
at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
at Array. (module.js:421:10)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

whereas this line is line 12 on app.js:

```
var helpers = require('express-helpers')(app);
```

and if I make it

```
var helpers = require('express-helpers');
```

it does throw the error, but also does not work.

My top of the app.js file is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.listen(34573);

// !Requires
var helpers = require('express-helpers')(app);
```

Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.

It turns out that I had my links mixed, and the usage I was trying was meant for a forked branch. I cloned the branch, and overwrote the default https://github.com/masahiroh/express-helpers and the code worked as it was supposed to with the correct branch.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass to app.locals() :

```
var helpers = require('express-helpers')();

app.locals ({
        "form_tag" : helpers.form_tag,
        "form_tag_end" : helpers.form_end_tag,
        "link_to" : helpers.link_to,
        "input_field_tag" : helpers.input_field_tag,
        "submit_tag" : helpers.submit_tag
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I know this is really late, however I am the author of the fork you are are talking about. It is the maintained version of the express-helpers module and should be used for future versions.

The problem that you were having is that you should be requiring the helpers before you call app.listen(). app.listen() should really be the last thing in your file especially anything concerning app setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this npm package who provide better & extended helpers.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-view-helpers

`npm install native-view-helpers --save`

Hope it'll help someone.